# What happens with bitwise shift for all 8 bits

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a small query in c,
I am using the bitwise left shift on number 69 which is `01000101` in binary

```
01000101  << 8
```

and I get answer as `100010100000000`

Shouldn't it be all 8 zeros i.e. `00000000`  as we shift all the 8 bits to left and then pad with zeros.

Comment: depends how wide is your variable.. Looks like 16 bits

Comment: if you say int i = 01000101 << 8; then i is 32 bits and the answer you see is expected.

Comment: In my code i have used int

Comment: All integer arithmetic (including shifts) is done in at least `int` precision

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the literal (default data type) for a number (`int`) is, in most of nowadays CPU, greater than `8-bit` (typically `32-bit`) and thus when you apply

```
69 << 8 //note 69 is int
```

It is actually applied like this

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000101 << 8
```

Thus you get the result

```
00000000 00000000 01000101 00000000
```

If you use, say, `unsigned char` specifically, then it won't happen:

```
unsigned char a = 69 << 8; //resulting in 0
```

This is because though `69 << 8` itself will still result in

```
01000101 00000000
```

But the above value will be casted to `8-bit` `unsigned char`, resulting in:

```
00000000
```

Comment: So you means the answer is 00000000 00000000 01000101 00000000

Comment: @TechJ ah, yes. It depends on your CPU word length actually. But typically it is 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Bit shift operators act on entire objects, not individual bytes. If the object storing 69 is wider than 1 byte (int is typically 4 bytes for example), then the bits that are shifted outside of the first (lowest/rightmost) byte overflow and are "pushed into" the second byte. For example:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000101 //The number 69, stored in a 32 bit object
00000000 00000000 01010000 00000000 //shifted left by 8
```

If you had stored the number in a 1-byte variable, such as a char, the result would indeed have been zero.

```
           01000101 //The number 69, stored in an 8 bit object
(01000101) 00000000 //shifted left by 8
 ^^^^^^^^
these bits have been shifted outside the size of the object.
```

The same thing would happen if you shifted an int by 32.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01000101 //The number 69, stored in a 32 bit int
00000000 00000000 01010000 00000000 //shifted left by 8
00000000 01010000 00000000 00000000 //shifted left by 16
01010000 00000000 00000000 00000000 //shifted left by 24
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 //shifted left by 32, overflow
```

Comment: wrong. (bit shift) operators act on expressions, not variables.

Comment: @wildplasser replaced "variable" with "object."

Comment: It is not an object (it need not have an addres, for instance) . It is an **expression**. consider the case `(a+b) <<c` Or a literal (like in the example): `1234 << x`

Comment: @wildplasser "A 32-bit expression" makes no sense to me. How do you suggest I rephrase my answer?